# Trying to reset password holding Command+R, at Startup, goes to Wi-Fi

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, password, utilities

I am holding <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> at Startup, but can't access Utilities, it goes directly to Wi-Fi, choose network.

Answer (score 2):

From [OS X: About OS X Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)

> OS X Internet Recovery
>
> Newer Macs include the ability to start up directly from an
>   Internet-based version OS X Recovery. Your Mac automatically uses this
>   feature when the Recovery System on the startup drive isn't available.
>   For example, if your startup drive encounters an issue, or if your
>   startup drive has been replaced or erased. Internet Recovery lets you
>   start your Mac directly from Apple's servers. Starting up from this
>   system performs a quick test of your memory and hard drive to check
>   for hardware issues.
>
> Internet Recovery initially asks you to select a Wi-Fi network and
>   enter a network password when needed. Next, Internet Recovery
>   downloads and starts from a Recovery System image. From there, you are
>   offered the same utilities and options as the Recovery System on a
>   startup drive.

Answer (score 0):

Your need to press at the proper time and hold.

If you are trying to reset your password - that is windows, not Mac.

Some Mac features are available by holding down certain keys during startup.

Press and hold the keys immediately after you turn on your Mac and hear the startup sound. Keep holding until the described behavior occurs. These combinations work with Intel-based Mac computers.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

Comment: Exactly what is "If you are trying to reset your password - that is windows, not Mac." supposed to mean?  BTW Don't try editing my answer again with the same line of yours I just quoted from your answer!  The OP obviously has a Mac and this has nothing to do with Windows!

Comment: The title of the question says 'Trying to reset password holding Command+R, at Startup, goes to Wi-Fi' and that is a Windows startup keystroke, our Macs are as otherwise stated.

Comment: From [Startup key combinations for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) "Command (⌘)-R Start up from OS X Recovery."!  Read my answer as to a possible reason why it's going directly to Wi-Fi. "Your Mac automatically uses this feature when the Recovery System on the startup drive isn't available." and "Internet Recovery initially asks you to select a Wi-Fi network"

Comment: I understand and agree with you, my comment was supposed to refer to my answer. It should not have been an edit to your answer. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, however if you agree with me then what you said "If you are trying to reset your password - that is windows, not Mac." makes no sense at all, especially considering the information presented in my previous comment.

Comment: My comment makes no sense as an edit to your answer and was an error, my answer has that comment as a qualification. If one was both a Mac & Windows user it may make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26638/discussion-between-scott-porter-and-user3439894).

Comment: Ask Different is for Q&A for (power) users of Apple hardware and software, has nothing to do with a Windows PC, only Windows from Boot Camp and Windows from Boot Camp is not going to respond to "Command (⌘)-R at the Mac's startup chime in the context of the OP's question, that is pressing Command (⌘)-R at Startup. So regardless the statement "If you are trying to reset your password - that is windows, not Mac." is totally illogical and irrelevant here!  No need to discuss it further.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not holding down the Option key together with the mentioned above two keys (Command+R).

As of the description here (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255), if you hold down the Command+R keys while restarting, your system is going to boot into Recovery mode and then from the menu bar you will be able to access the Reset Password option (as far as I remember it).

Or you can also try the way that is explained here (http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/reset-forgotten-admin-password-mac-osx).